# Quotient space of harmonic functions on punctured plane

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be $n$ distinct points in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\Omega := \mathbb{C} \setminus \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Define $H(\Omega)$ to be the space of harmonic functions on $\Omega$ and $R(\Omega)$ the subspace of $H(\Omega)$ consisting of real parts of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$. I want to show that the equivalence classes of 
$$\log\vert z - a_1 \vert,\ldots, \log \vert z - a_n \vert$$
form a basis for the quotient space $H(\Omega)/R(\Omega)$. I know how to show linear independence. I have seen rather lengthy arguments that the above functions span the space, but I am wondering if there is a way to show that the dimension of $H(\Omega)/R(\Omega)$ must be $n$ without actually computing a basis. That way I can conclude the above functions form a basis based on their linear independence.

Comment: $H(\Omega)$ usually means the holomorphic functions on $\Omega.$ You might want to write $h(\Omega)$ here.

Comment: It's been a while, but if I recall correctly we can more or less prove this using basic complex analysis. For example, I seem to recall the following result is contained in Ahlfors in some form (copied from [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_13/HFT.pdf) for ease):

Comment: **Logarithmic Conjugation Theorem:** Let $\Omega$ be a finitely connected domain. Let $K_1, \ldots, K_m$ be the bounded components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Omega,$ and let $a_j \in K_j$ for $j=1, \ldots m.$ If $u$ is real valued and harmonic on $\Omega,$ then there exist $f$ holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$u(z) = \Re f(z) + b_1 \log |z-a_1| + \cdots + b_m \log|z - a_m|$$ for all $z \in \Omega$

Comment: This can be done without resorting to linear algebra if I recall correctly. It more or less comes from the Schwartz Integral formula with some observations and a bit of calculation